# Invalid use of incomplete typedef of a struct in C

Tags: c, struct, abstract-data-type

I am using ADT's to hide the implementation of the structs and functions

Here is the library website.h:

```
#define WEBSITE_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct website WEBSITE;

WEBSITE website_create();
void website_apagar(WEBSITE **website);
#endif
```

In the website.c part is the implementation of both functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "website.h"

struct website{
    char titulo[40];
    char url[512];
};

WEBSITE website_create(){
    WEBSITE site;
    scanf("%s",site.titulo);
    scanf("%s",site.url);

    return site;
}
```

In my main function I do include "website.h", but when I try to declare a type/call a function, like the following:

```
WEBSITE *site = malloc(sizeof(WEBSITE));
*site = website_create();
```

I get the following errors:

```
invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type
invalid use of incomplete typedef ‘WEBSITE’
```

Comment: Have you defined the `website` struct? It sounds like that's missing.

Comment: it is defined in the website.c file. I editted the question for clarity

Comment: Is `main` in `website.c` ? If not, it can't see the definition of the `website` struct, so the `typedef` is an incomplete type. Try moving the definition of the `website` struct to `website.h`.

Comment: Worked!!!! Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Note that although `WEBSITE website_create();` declares the function, it does not specify the function's prototype.  It merely says the function exists, returns the relevant type, and has an unspecified argument list — so it can be called with any set of arguments, including no arguments.  If the function takes no arguments, write the full prototype: `WEBSITE website_create(void);`.  Now you can't call it with any arguments (assuming the prototype is visible at the time of use).

Comment: Note that you can only pass and return pointers to incomplete types, or pointers to pointers to incomplete types, etc.  You could use `extern WEBSITE *website_create(void);` returning a pointer to the created website.  That would be an opaque type — and would allow you to hide the details of the structure, which is what is normally meant by an ADT.  If you move the definition of `struct website` into the header, then it will certainly work, but it is no longer an ADT, nor is it an opaque type or a complete type.